Applet with JavaSE 17
I studied Java 2 a long time ago and now I would like to create applets for fun. I'm working with Eclipse and I have installed avaSE17 but it seems that the updates of the last few years do not allow importing java.awt.* and java.applet.*.
How can I create applets with java 17?
TY
I hope someone can show me an example. A simple text displayed on a window it will be enough.
TY

You can't. Java applets are no longer a thing and were deprecated in 2017 with Java 9.

I’m voting to close this question because Applets are beyond deprecated any new project should avoid them. Why do you want to use an Applet?

Only for study.

The simplest thing to do would be to use swing. This will create an window and does not require a browser.
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextOnAWindow{

    public void createAndShow(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");
        frame.add(new JLabel("Hello World");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( 
          ()->{
              new TextOnAWindow().createAndShow();
          });
    }

}

Maybe check a tutorial first to get a better idea. Avoid the netbeans part, unless you want to use netbeans.

This creates a standard desktop app with a Swing GUI, not a browser applet.

@NSarj That is true. Their question just says "window" so maybe they though doing it in the browser would be easiest.
